# Javascript typewriter does not write and backspace properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a simple JavaScript/jQuery typewriter with backspacing, which loops through several messages (& a background image).

The problem I'm facing is that as the functions loop, they are not written out properly - missing several of the characters.

i.e. my array is [everyone, dog owners, the diet-conscious, workers, families] but what will get written in turn is: ryone, g owners, diet-conscious, (blank), families.

I think the problem could be that a variable somewhere is not being reset properly or the length is being worked out from the previous message - possible scoping issues.

On Codepen: https://codepen.io/nathankeenmelb/pen/MOovXJ?editors=0010

**The relevant HTML**

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h2>There's something for<span id="message"> everyone.</span></h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

**The JS, with jQuery**

```js
let messages = [
  " everyone.",
  " dog owners.",
  " the diet-conscious.",
  " workers.",
  " families."
];
let images = [
  "url(https://via.placeholder.com/200x100)",
  "url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x100)",
  "url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x200)",
  "url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x300)",
  "url(https://via.placeholder.com/400x400)"
];

let loopDuration = 3000;

function displayImages(arr){
  //Loop through other images, but start at second item
    let j = 1;
    setInterval( //evaluates every x ms
        function(){ 
            $('body').css("background-image",arr[j]);
            j++;
          console.log('j in image = ' + j);
          //Reset loop after been through them all to repeat
            if(j >= images.length) j = 0;
          //Interval length in ms
        }, loopDuration);
}

function displayMessages() {

  //CHANGE THE MESSAGE -starting the loop
    let i = 0;
    setInterval( //evaluates every x ms
        function(){
            //TYPEWRITE MESSAGE
            let char = 0;
            function typeWriter() {
              //for as long as the current character length is less than the full character length

              if (char < messages[i].length) {
                //Add the next character to the html
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += messages[i].charAt(char);

                //Go to next character
                char++;
                //Wait x ms to write next character
                setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
              }

            } //end typewriter()

          //Run the function
          typeWriter();

          //START BACKSPACE
          let theMessage = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML;
          let bchar = theMessage.length;

          function backSpacer() {
            if (bchar > 0) {
              theMessage = theMessage.slice(0,-1);
              document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = theMessage;
              bchar--;
              //Run the function again, after x m
              setTimeout(backSpacer, 25);
            }
          }
          //Run the function
          backSpacer();

          //If instead of using backspacer() I deleted the text as follows, that worked fine
          //$('#message').text('');
          //document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";


          //Having typed it all out, backspaced it, go to the next message
          i++;

          //Having gone through each message, reset loop to repeat, to 0 to include the original
            if(i >= messages.length) i = 0;
          //Interval length in ms
        }, loopDuration);

}

//Wait till the whole page loads
window.onload = function loadChanges() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //Run whatever after time elapses
    displayImages(images);
    displayMessages();
    //Wait x ms after page loads
  }, 1000)
};
```

Comment: Troubleshooting pro tip #1: Simplify.  This is a big, difficult set of code to navigate.  Break it down into the smallest part possible, work it, test it, get it working (or figure out what's wrong with it), then build upon it.  Attempting to tackle something with so much code and recursion and timeouts all at once - that's more work than you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code a bit. It seems to me like you were running both `typeWriter` and `backSpacer` at the same time.

Your code had this structure (I've simplified it a lot):

```
setInterval(function(){
  function typeWriter() {
    if (char < messages[i].length) {
      char++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
    }

  }

  typeWriter();

  let bchar = theMessage.length;

  function backSpacer() {
    if (bchar > 0) {
      bchar--;
      setTimeout(backSpacer, 25);
    }
  }

  backSpacer();
}, loopDuration);
```

As you can see you call both typeWriter and backSpacer. The setTimeout will cause these methods to run "in parallel" and therefore remove and add letters at the same time causing the message to be messed up.

I created a working example that is more of a state machine. Meaning that it will first type the message. When that is done it will switch to erasing the message. And when that is done it will wait to restart.

The code isn't great, but it sorta works and might help you get to a working solution. Let me know in the comments if you have any questions.

https://codepen.io/andreasmcdermott/pen/ZaXXyK?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks, you worked out the problem and provided a better way of getting the timing right. I think I can see the logic of your solution, so, I'll call this the solution.